# Custom MVC model binding on a type with no public properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created strongly typed ID classes in my project as there is currently confusion with interchangeable string ID's which is causing bugs which are easy to miss.

I have changed all the `string id` parameters in my action methods to the new strongly typed to realise that the MVC model binder can not now bind the strings to the new type (despite implicit string conversion operators existing for this type).

e.g.

```
public ActionResult Index(JobId jobId)
{
  //...
}
```

I have read around about creating custom model binders, but all the tutorials are about binding a POCO class when we know the names of the query parameters / form values.

I just want to be able to tell the framework 'if parameter is strongly typed id type, instantiate using this constructor', so it will always work no matter what the name of the parameter is.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT**

This is the base class that the strongly typed ID's inherit from:

```
public class StronglyTypedId
{    
    private readonly string _id;

    public StronglyTypedId(string id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(StronglyTypedId a, StronglyTypedId b)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(a, b))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (((object)a != null) && ((object)b == null) || ((object)a == null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return a._id == b._id;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(StronglyTypedId a, StronglyTypedId b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _id;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is StronglyTypedId))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return ((StronglyTypedId)obj)._id == _id;
    }

    public Guid ToGuid()
    {
        return Guid.Parse(_id);
    }

    public bool HasValue()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: if JobId has a property `id` the binding will work correctly.

Comment: @Shoe no the JobId has no public properties

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin can you expand on this please?

Comment: Can you post your JobId class?

Comment: What's the intention with that? You could create a model binder than binds parameter `id` into a "new" JobId, but that's really creating work for yourself to accomplish the same thing that's already done.

Comment: @Shoe, that's why I asked him to post the JobId class. The class only has a constructor with no public properties. That's why model binding doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do this just now using a custom model binder. This way will work no matter what the name of the parameter that needs to be bound:

```
public class JobIdModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(JobId))
        {
            var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
            string id = value.AttemptedValue;

            return new JobId(id);
        }
        else
        {
            return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }
    }
}
```

So it's pretty much the same as if you are implementing a custom binder for a specific model type, except this is the bit of magic `var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName)` which means it will work regardless of naming of parameters.

Then you simply register the binder in your `Global.cs` like so:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(JobId), new JobIdModelBinder());
```

Comment: "which means it will work regardless of naming of parameters." Well no, your model name is JobId so if the parameter is anything but that it isn't going to bind. Plus in order to bind at all the model type has to be a JobId for the page. Doesn't seem very useful to me because it's not very reusable. If it works for you great.

Comment: @Shoe I actually tested this out and ModelName was not equal to JobId, it was the name of the parameter name (looks like some dodgy property naming in the framework)

Comment: @Shoe and it also works in action methods that have other parameters as well as the JobId model, so it is actually highly re-usable!